# SQL Server 2008 (SP4) Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

This query on SQL server 2008 (SP4) has worked correctly until yesterday morning.

Today returns an incomprehensible error for me.

I need replace the values **';'** to **'-'** of column **RisInt** and **RisNot** in my SQL Server table.

I have tried with SQL syntax **UPDATE IGNORE** without success.

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

My SQL code below.

```
UPDATE [DBO].[Details]
SET RisInt = REPLACE(RisInt, ';', '-'),
 RisNot = REPLACE(RisNot, ';', '-')

[Err] 21000 - [SQL Server]Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or
when the subquery is used as an expression.
01000 - [SQL Server]The statement has been terminated.
```

**#Edit 01**

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @IGI VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @IGI = (SELECT a.IGXF FROM DBO.Details a, DELETED i
WHERE a.IGXF = i.IGXF)
    DELETE FROM DBO.SUPPORT where IGBA = @IGI

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
```

Comment: Post the code for the UPDATE trigger on the table.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm sorry don't understand

Comment: The error is not returned by your query. There is an `UPDATE` trigger on the table that is incorrectly coded. From SSMS Object Explorere, browse to the `dbo.Details` table and expand the Triggers node. Right-click on the trigger name and select script as create and post the code.

Comment: @DanGuzman Okay thank you. Please see **#Edit 01** in my first question I have renamed the table from 'details' to 'dettaglio' for testing

Comment: Post the code, not an image, of the trigger definition.

Comment: @DanGuzman Okay, I have replaced image with code  of the trigger definition on **#Edit 01** in my first question

Comment: You need to find the person who wrote this trigger and get a refund. This trigger has redundant code, does not allow for more than one row to be updated at a time, and is probably deleting records that it shouldn't be. It's difficult to rewrite this trigger properly for you because it appears to be doing something incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT @IGI = (SELECT a.IGXF FROM DBO.Details a, DELETED i WHERE
>   a.IGXF = i.IGXF)
>
> DELETE FROM DBO.SUPPORT where IGBA = @IGI

A common mistake made when writing triggers is to assume a single row is affected. The scalar subquery above will fail when more than one row is returned.

Below is an untested example of how the trigger code can be refactored to handle multiple rows. This also uses ANSI-92 SQL style joins rather than the old syntax.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM dbo.SUPPORT
WHERE IGBA IN(
    SELECT a.IGXF
    FROM dbo..Details AS a
    JOIN DELETED  AS i ON
        a.IGXF = i.IGXF
    );
```